# Cannot Shut Google play music

Tags: google-play-music

Whenever I go to shut google play music, it does, and then opens again. And again.  Et cetera. Reboots do not really help (Play music starts up after a minute) and safe mode makes no difference, neither does cache clearing, force stopping, clear data, or even uninstalling and reinstalling. Does anyone know what I can do to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings > Apps >Google Play Music and  click disable. Or if you can root your phone you can permanently delete it.

Comment: I have no disable option, for some reason. And No to rooting. Also, I still want to use it sometimes.

Comment: What phone do you have?  And which OS is it on?

Comment: Samsung galaxy S3 running android 4.3. Google play music SHOULD have been pre-installed, but it was not, so no disable

Comment: You Mightve downloaded the wrong version of play music. But try first to move the file and.

Comment: Apk to sd and u can probably freeze it.

Comment: Or download ESfile manager and delete the files țhrough there.

Comment: Ok. Lets give it a go

Comment: Good luck,  lmk how you fair.

Comment: There we go! Moving to sd then deleting the files on sd worked. Dunno why, im sure the configs stay internal.... oh well! Add these bits into your answer, so I can mark it correct